# How to Refactor multiple elif statements with CSV, i dont know how to approach it im a beginner

Tags: python, refactoring

(The "anykey" has not been used in the process)

def load1():
print(
"Please choose your region\n 1 for Region 1\n 2 for CAR \n 3 for Region II\n 4 for Region III\n 5 for Region IV\n 6 for NCR\n 7 for Region V\n 8 for Region VI\n 9 for Region VII\n 10 for SOCCSKARGEN\n 11 for Region VIII\n 12 for CARAGA\n 13 for Region IX\n 14 for Region X\n 15 for Region XI ")
option = int(input("Your option: "))
# Acts like switch
if option == 1:
print("Region 1\n")
csv_file = csv.reader(open('file/Region I.csv', 'r'))
for row in csv_file:
print(row)
anykey = input("Press any key to return from main menu")
mainMenu()

```
elif option == 2:
    print("CAR\n")
    csv_file = csv.reader(open('file/CAR.csv', 'r'))
    for row in csv_file:
        print(row)
    anykey = input("Press any key to return from main menu")
    mainMenu()

elif option == 3:
    print("Region 2\n")
    csv_file = csv.reader(open('file/Region II.csv', 'r'))
    for row in csv_file:
        print(row)
    anykey = input("Press any key to return from main menu")
    mainMenu()

elif option == 4:

    print("Region 3\n")
    csv_file = csv.reader(open('file/Region III.csv', 'r'))
    for row in csv_file:
        print(row)
    anykey = input("Press any key to return from main menu")
    mainMenu()

elif option == 5:
    print("Region 4\n")
    csv_file = csv.reader(open('file/Region IV.csv', 'r'))
    for row in csv_file:
        print(row)
    anykey = input("Press any key to return from main menu")
    mainMenu()

elif option == 6:
    print("NCR 4\n")
    csv_file = csv.reader(open('file/NCR.csv', 'r'))
    for row in csv_file:
        print(row)
        print()
    anykey = input("Press any key to return from main menu")
    mainMenu()

elif option == 7:
    print("Region 5\n")
    csv_file = csv.reader(open('file/Region V.csv', 'r'))
    for row in csv_file:
        print(row)
    anykey = input("Press any key to return from main menu")
    mainMenu()

elif option == 8:
    print("Region 6\n")
    csv_file = csv.reader(open('file/Region VI.csv', 'r'))
    for row in csv_file:
        print(row)
    anykey = input("Press any key to return from main menu")
    mainMenu()

elif option == 9:
    print("Region 7\n")
    csv_file = csv.reader(open('file/Region VII.csv', 'r'))
    for row in csv_file:
        print(row)
    anykey = input("Press any key to return from main menu")
    mainMenu()

elif option == 10:
    print("SOCCSKARGEN\n")
    csv_file = csv.reader(open('file/SOCCSKARGEN.csv', 'r'))
    for row in csv_file:
        print(row)
    anykey = input("Press any key to return from main menu")
    mainMenu()

elif option == 11:
    print("Region 8\n")
    csv_file = csv.reader(open('file/Region VIII.csv', 'r'))
    for row in csv_file:
        print(row)
    anykey = input("Press any key to return from main menu")
    mainMenu()

elif option == 12:
    print("CARAGA\n")
    csv_file = csv.reader(open('file/CARAGA.csv', 'r'))
    for row in csv_file:
        print(row)
    anykey = input("Press any key to return from main menu")
    mainMenu()

elif option == 13:
    print("Region 9\n")
    csv_file = csv.reader(open('file/Region IX.csv', 'r'))
    for row in csv_file:
        print(row)
    anykey = input("Press any key to return from main menu")
    mainMenu()

elif option == 14:
    print("Region 10\n")
    csv_file = csv.reader(open('file/Region X.csv', 'r'))
    for row in csv_file:
        print(row)
    anykey = input("Press any key to return from main menu")
    mainMenu()

elif option == 15:
    print("Region 11\n")
    csv_file = csv.reader(open('file/Region XI.csv', 'r'))
    for row in csv_file:
        print(row)
    anykey = input("Press any key to return from main menu")
    mainMenu()
```

Comment: This method is suppose to be loaded when called

Comment: Well. You say you don't know how to approach it (refactoring), so I'll give you a couple of hints:
Look for repeated code, like the `csv.reader(open('file/Region [x].csv', 'r')` and the 
`anykey = input("Press any key to return from main menu")`.
Why not create a simple function that takes a file name  as an argument and prints the contents + the static string + calls mainMenu(), repeated in each elif?  
You could maybe use a dict to hold mappings for integer input -> file name and using a switch statement for calling this function instead of all the elifs? Just some thoughts...

Answer (score 0):

Create an array with the names of the csv files using the index for the region.

Then simply use the region selected as the index to get the csv file name:

```
regions = [ 'Region 1', 'CAR', 'Region II' ]

# do your selection code (you can also loop the regions array for the list)
print( "Please choose your region")
index = 1
for region in regions:
    print(index + " for " + region)
    index++

option = int(input("Your option: "))

regionString = reginos[option-1]
print(regionString)
csv_file = csv.reader(open('file/' + regionString + '.csv', 'r'))
for row in csv_file:
    print(row)
anykey = input("Press any key to return from main menu")
mainMenu()
```